# VS Code Not Showing Output From Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have always used VS Code on my mac but have recently installed on windows PC.

I have installed node. In VS Code I have installed Code Runner and JavaScript (ES6) code snippets.

However, when I try to run the programme, I get the [running] and [done] outputs from VS Code, but nothing shows.

I am fairly new to this, and have exhausted every option I could find on Google. Any help will be much appreciated.

[pic of output in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGmuY.png)
[pic when I try to do it in VS Code terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfzuM.png)

Comment: you have no output when running it in both cases. possibly because you have not saved the file

Answer (score 0):

Please notice the white dot next to the name of the file on the tab.  This indicates you have not SAVED your file contents.  When you run the code, it runs the saved file.  Please save the file and try again.